# Man/Doc helps save Space Whale alien- short story

Tags: story-identification, space

I read this short sci-fi story in a book awhile ago.

Some Man/Doctor who is on this planet is asked by the inhabitants to look at this enormous creature/whale/ship that has landed on the planet but for some reason isn't leaving like it usually does (the creature landing is a normal occurrence). This worries the inhabitants because they tell him that the alien is long lived and capable of folding itself into N-space, and that what you see isn't all of it and that if it dies while on the planet it will unfold and obliterate everyone.

The man as he approaches the alien sees the supplies that the people gave it and the aliens tentacles hanging outside itself unable to do anything, he crawls inside the creature which is part flesh and part ship and reaches its brain center where he discovers the alien has a tumor growing on its brain. Not knowing about its physiology he decides to operate and is horrified that the best he can do is mutilate half the tumor off which helps the alien. The grateful alien in the end saves him and the people from pirates by sacrificing itself and squashing the pirates. He decides to study the alien remains to help its other kind for the rest of his life.

Comment: I don't think it's the story you're looking for, but one of James White's Sector General stories had the human doctor climbing inside a huge alien to operate on what was thought to be a tumour/ulcer.

Comment: Thanks Daniel Roseman but I just looked that up and its not the story.

Comment: Another similar one is _Country Doctor_ by William Morrison. It also reminds me of something else (can't remember title or author). Must be  a common theme.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I've read that, however title/author are forgotten. IIRC it's a chapter in a full novel, not a short story. I'm gonna lose sleep now brooding over this story!